# How to list all undefined variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following well-known situation:

```
var x = 1;
function f () {
  console.log(x);
  var x = 3;
  console.log(x);
}
f();
```

In this case the output will be:

```
undefined
3
```

So I would like to list all the 'undefined' variables that are read before they received any value. Is it possible to do somehow?

Comment: How can you list something undefined ?

Comment: Static code analysis? (gcc tells me when I use a variable prior to set a value to it)

Comment: Probably any reasonable advanced IDE will give you a hint regarding `x`.

Comment: It's not possible to that in command line interface?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Resharper could help inspect undefined variable?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My answer gives not a program generated list of all undefined variables, but helps to detect this situation:

Use http://www.jslint.com/ or http://www.javascriptlint.com/ to analyze your program(fragment). It gives you hints about un- or wrongdeclared variables and helps you producing code of higher quality (see also  Douglas Crockford: JavaScript The Good Parts)

Comment: unfortunately neither of them displays these variables

Comment: My proposal was too short; you have to use strict mode and correct indents, to get the hint "Redefinition of 'x' from line 1."  to the problem in " console.log(x);"